# Read write a java class file

Tags: java

I have a rather strange requirement. I have property files in which same keys are added and a respective java constant is created in interface file.

I want to relive myself of adding into all the files again and again.I know how to read write property file. Is there a way to read / write java file. I mean not the usual file read APIs like

```
JavaFileReader jfr;
jfr.AddField("fdsf");
```

I understand its very specific requirement.But hoping someone else also has the need:):)

Comment: @Ravisha : I am not sure if I understand what you are asking... Do you want to modify already compiled `.class` files based on the contents of a `.properties` file? Or do you want to automatically update the contents of `.java` files based on the contents of a `.properties` file?

Comment: Its the .java file which needs to be modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [codemodel](https://codemodel.dev.java.net/). Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121324/a-java-api-to-generate-java-source-files). It might help on how to use it.

Comment: Looks more or less the thing what i was looking for.Thanks rok