# Java/Scala library to generate Java source code

Tags: java, scala, code-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Java API to generate Java source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121324/a-java-api-to-generate-java-source-files)

Is there a good library for generating Java source code (*not* bytecode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeModel and Eclipse JDT worked for [this fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121324/a-java-api-to-generate-java-source-files), and he ultimately chose CodeModel.

Comment: Then isn't this question just a dup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/ i use this to rewrite huge portions of my existing code base, also ASTs can be constructed with this and it is a readable wrapper written over eclipse core....