# Elegant way for C++ code generation

Tags: c++, code-generation

I am currently working on a database related project in which I generate a lot of C++ code. This code is compiled then and loaded as a dynamic library. I use this techniques to build efficient code for the database schema and queries.

Currently, I am using simple file write to generate the code (what was okay for the proof-of-concept implementation). Now, I am searching for a more elegant but comparable flexible solution to generate C++ code.

I searched quite a lot but all the solutions I found so far are rather complex/extensive, not efficient enough, or not flexible enough.

What libraries are you using in your C++ projects to generate code?

Best,
Moritz

Comment: Personally, I just use Python to do all my code generation without even any code-generation-intended libraries (like cheetah). Never had any issues, and since it's just Python everybody understands it.

Comment: But I am programming a C++ program which generates C++ code which is loaded & executed dynamically as a shared library.

Comment: One of the most impressive rule-object implementations I've ever seen was done by a colleague. The project was Java, and he wrote a translator that would generate compilable optimized Java code from the rule-language in use (they were Sexps as i recall). Sent to the compiler (shipped with the product), the resulting .class file was databased and loaded via a chiseled-up class loader on-demand, then sent to the rule engine for eval as-needed. It was beautiful. I always wanted to try the same thing with dll/so files and C++. Sounds similar to what you're doing.

Comment: Try yb-orm https://github.com/vnaydionov/yb-orm/wiki

Comment: I am not quite sure why an ORM should help me here? It is not really flexible and adaptable to my needs. Furthermore, the database project I work on is not a relational database.

Comment: You could look into using the clang library to compile the code for you. That would seem a little cleaner to me, as it saves a call to `system()` to run the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [program transformation system (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) to define and compose code templates in a reliable way.

Most PTS enable one to define a grammar, and then parse source code into ASTs using that grammar.  More importantly, they accept *patterns*: source code fragments (usually of a nonterminal or a list of nonterminals) with placeholders that correspond to wellformed sub-fragments (nonterminals representing subtrees).  These patterns usually insist that a named placeholder match identically (see example below).  Such patterns can be used to match against a parsed AST as a way to find code fragments using the surface syntax.

So, one might use a pattern:

```
   pattern x_squared(t: term): product
      = " \t * \t ";
```

to hunt for subexpressions which consist of products of identical subtrees.
This will match

```
   (p + q[17])*(p+q[17)
```

but not

```
    2 * (x-3)
```

But just as interestingly, such patterns can be used as *code generators*, by instantiating the pattern with bound value (trees) for the variables.  So,
"instantiate x_squared(2^x)" produces

```
     (2^x)*(2^x)
```

By itself, this is just a fancy sort of macro scheme.  It is a lot better, in that it can tell you "at compile time" (for the patterns) whether what you are composing makes sense or not.   So you get type checking of the composition of the code fragments.  For instance, you might accidentally code "instantiate x_squared(int q)", but a good PTS will object that "int q" is not a "term"; you find the bug when you build the code generator.

Where this gets really interesting is where one can build many different code fragments, from many different patterns, and compose those fragments with yet more patterns. This allows one to build very complex code.  All of this is a (syntax-type) safe way; resulting trees are valid syntax. (You can still bollix semantics; nothing is perfect).  As the complexity of the code you can generate goes up, it is good to have this additional checking to help you avoid generating bad code.

A PTS has an additional advantage: after composing code fragments, it can apply source-to-source transformations to optimize the resulting code.  Thus you can produce optimized code according to your ability to write matching transformations, and harnessing knowledge you have during code generation.
Imagine you generate code for a matrix multiply:

```
 ... P * Q ...
```

and your code generator somehow or other knows that Q is an identity matrix.
Then the following optimization can remove an expensive matrix multiply:

```
  rule optimize_matrix_times_unit(m: term, n: term): product -> product
       " \m * \q "
   ->  " \m "
    if is_identity_matrix(q)
```

This transformation takes advantage of pattern matching (to find a matrix product) in the generated code,  pattern instantiation (to generate a replacement for the matched product), and additional knowledge or analysis (is_identity_matrix) that the code generation can do.

You need a PTS capable of handling C++ parsing; those are a bit hard to find.  The one I designed (DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit) happens to do this.  The examples in this answer are DMS-style.

Here's [a technical paper](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/WCRE05.pdf) that describes a large-scale reengineering task done by DMS on C++ code. A number of examples in the paper are actually quite complex patterns used to instantiate code; the reengineering task had to generate a new set of APIs for an existing chunk of code.

Comment: Very interesting topic. I don't understand yet whether such code synthesis is flexible enough for my case. I will definitely give it a closer look. But I guess it will be something I will mention under "Future work" for my current project ;)

Comment: I can assure, by design, and from experience of using this tool for 20+ years (check my bio), that it is extremely flexible; many languages, many code generation/transformation/analysis tasks.  We have generated huge programs with this.  Can you describe what flexibility you think you need?  I might be able to respond constructively.

Comment: I think I don't need the entire funtionality of your tool. 

Currently, I have a tree-like C++ structure of algebra operators and you can call produce on the root to start the code-generation process for a specific query (which was translated in such an operator tree). Operators generate their code when produce is called and they can force their childs to produce their code and so on. This results in data-centric query code (Thomas Neumann proposed this data-centric query processing approach - http://hyper-db.de/).

Comment: Currently, I generate the operator's code (in the produce method) by writing it to a file via <<. This makes it hard to understand the functionality of an operator because its code consist mainly of such file writes to generate code for it. My goal is to make the operators funtionality better understandable by hiding the code generation somehow.

Comment: You may not need all that power; you asked what was available and used.  What it sounds like you have is a classic recursive tree walk from a root, printing ("<<") text strings as you go; with such a scheme, you can't post-process the generated answer in any useful way.   You can see what DMS (and similarly, other PTS tools) patterns look like; no "printing" at all, just the skeleton of the generaed code.  One composes patterns to generate a tree; a final step prettyprints the tree as valid text.   See the referenced paper for some interesting generator patterns.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a closer look!