# Auto Generate code in java based on templates

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a eclipse plugin and I want to add a capability to generate java code blocks based on simple template or anything simple. Something like generate source for constructors or getters and setters that java editor provides.

I have seen the JET articles : https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET2/jet_tutorial2.html  but I want something simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Java API to generate Java source files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121324/a-java-api-to-generate-java-source-files)

Answer (score -2):

Eclipse already some has it built in:

```
1. Highlight your field
2. Right Click -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters
```

Also you can use the wizards to create a basic java class.

```
1. File -> New -> Class
```

etc.

You can also look up this related question:

[A Java API to generate Java source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121324/a-java-api-to-generate-java-source-files#136016)

Comment: Yes ..I know and that's what I want to build for my custom plugin ..which will generate code like this..

Comment: Google: Eclipse JDT AST